Sequence approaching a sup of an inf
Let $f(x,y):X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ and consider a sequence $x_k,y_k$ such that $\lim_k f(x_k,y_k)=\sup_{x\in X}\inf_{y\in Y} f(x,y)$.
Is it true that $\lim_k \inf_{y\in Y} f(x_k,y)= \sup_{x\in X}\inf_{y\in Y} f(x,y)$?
I'm sorry because probably it is very stupid but I was unable to prove it, now I'm starting to believe that there could be some counterexamples.
